# Can I earn interest from 457 plan?

Tags: riba, investment

Since I work for the government company we get [457 plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/457_plan) similar to [401k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/401(k)).

Can I earn interest from that and not from the bank?

If not what are my other options?

Comment: Please explain what those terms are. You can't ask us to check them out.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser I think 457 and 401k plans are well-enough known (at least in the U.S.) that a link to Wikipedia should be sufficient to not require a full explanation of how they work.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't earn interest from anyone.

If you are forced to receive interest, give it to charity.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit? In particular, a solution to the inflation and saving up for retirement - If you give away the interest you earn for retirement, and considering inflation, you would end up with very little money near the end.

Comment: Covering inflation does not constitute interest. RIBA in Arabic means increase, so long as your purchasing power is the same, there has been no increase in your wealth and its not riba. Cover inflation losses but don't go beyond that. Allah knows best.